# How to use AddForce and Velocity together?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have the jump component who use the AddForce for jumping and the movement component who move left and right using the Velocity.

If you don't move the character when your are jumping the jumping will be fine but when you move the character and jump at the same time then the movement component will break the jumping because the velocity is setting up a Vector2 point where define the Y axis too. I tried to use the current Y axis from the transform component in the movement but even that doesn't work.

What I should do for fix the problem between AddForce and then use Velocity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your move function is creating a new velocity vector and overwriting the existing one.

```
Vector2 velocityVector = rigidbody.velocity;    

velocityVector.x += movement * force;

rigidbody.velocity = velocityVector;
```

This will retain the existing velocity, both X and Y, and modify it. You will of course need to add deceleration (usually I use something along the lines of `if(grounded) velocityVector.x *= 0.999f;`, but I'm sure more fancy maths exists for more realistic deceleration) and some kind of maximum speed (again, I keep things simple and use similar to `if(velocityVector.x > maxSpeed) velocityVector.x = maxSpeed;`).

Comment: Yep, the idea is get the Y axis from the velocity instead of get it from the transform component. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

[`Rigidbody.AddForce`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) has the following definition:

```
public void AddForce(Vector3 force, ForceMode mode = ForceMode.Force);
```

One of the options available for [`ForceMode`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html) is [`ForceMode.VelocityChange`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.VelocityChange.html):

Add an instant velocity change to the rigidbody, ignoring its mass.

Apply the velocity change instantly with a single function call. In contrast to ForceMode.Impulse, VelocityChange will change the velocity of every rigidbody the same way regardless of differences in mass. This mode is useful for something like a fleet of differently-sized space ships that you want to control without accounting for differences in mass. In this mode, the unit of the force parameter is applied to the rigidbody as distance/time.

Comment: Thanks for the information, now I knew something new.